Using size_type as iterator offset - difference between GCC/Clang and MSVC
I'm trying to use size_type as offset to string iterator in std::copy() algorithm. When size_type is std::string::npos, GCC/Clang doesn't throw any exception but MSCV throws cannot seek string iterator before begin.
Why MSCV throws this exception? Which compiler is correct in this case?
I've tested the program using following compiler on compiler explorer:
GCC - x86-64 gcc 14.2
Clang - x86-64 clang 19.1.0
MSCV - x86 msvc v19.latest
Here is a minimal reproducible program
compiler Explorer
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <cstdint>
#include <string>

// timestamp in hhmmss.zzz format; can be in hhmmss format also
void test(const std::string& timestamp)
{
    std::string timeWithoutMs{};
    std::int32_t milliseconds{};

    auto itr = timestamp.find("."); 
    if( itr != std::string::npos)
    {
        milliseconds = std::stoi( timestamp.substr(itr + 1, timestamp.length() - itr));
    }

    std::copy( timestamp.begin(), timestamp.begin() + itr, std::back_inserter(timeWithoutMs));
    std::cout << timeWithoutMs << " - " << milliseconds << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    test("135523.495");  
    test("135523");      // MSVC throws exception here
}


std::copy( timestamp.begin(), timestamp.begin()+ -1 looks like UB for me.

So, its not required for GCC/Clang to throw an exception in this case?

Cleaner version of compiler explorer demo.

@DailyLearner no it's UB as the program breaks the pre-condition for std::copy, MSVC is just being helpful; you will probably find that MSVC only throws in debug mode not in release.

I think there is difference in implementation of std::copy gcc uses condition like it < end so copy ends immediately and MSVC it != end and this leads to buffer overflow. Anway your program is invalid.

BTW for clang libc++ standard library is used then address sanitizer reports an error: https://godbolt.org/z/xjr8rMovW (same crash as in case of MSVC).

The definition of std::string::npos is -1. As such, when itr is std::string::npos, that std::copy call looks like:
std::copy( timestamp.begin(), timestamp.begin() + -1, std::back_inserter(timeWithoutMs));

Note that in the second argument, you attempt to decrement the begin iterator of the string. MSVC's standard library chooses to diagnose this, as by default it has "checked iterators", which ensure the iterators are within bounds. GCC and Clang aren't required to diagnose this, so their behaviour is still correct, but your program is invalid, as you try to call std::copy with an invalid iterator range.
You can instead use std::string::substr, which is well-defined when the count argument is std::string::npos, and in this case runs up to the end of the string:
timeWithoutMs = timestamp.substr(0, itr);

I would also rename the itr variable to idx, since std::string::find returns an index rather than an iterator, and I think this adds to your confusion.

From CppReference: "Although the definition [of npos] uses -1, size_type is an unsigned integer type, and the value of npos is the largest positive value it can hold, due to signed-to-unsigned implicit conversion." In the call to std::copy, during argument evaluation, it is being converted back into a signed quantity. This is likely due to the definition of the operator+ function that is defined for the iterator.

@tbxfreeware Sure, but adding MAX_INT-1 ends up subtracting 1 anyhow thanks to 2s complement. (unless you do the math in a larger radix)

Yeah. There is an odd tension between size types (such as std::size_t and std::string::size_type), which are unsigned, and difference types (such as std::ptrdiff_t and std::string::difference_type), which are signed. Pointer and iterator arithmetic is generally carried out using diference types. That means that overflow (or wrapping) is inevitable when a size_type larger than std::numeric_limits<difference_type>::max() is converted to a difference_type of the same size. Beware.

The point made by @Yakk - Adam Nevraumont is that overflow (i.e., wrapping) would occur even if pointer and iterator arithmetic were carried out using unsigned types. As he said, that assumes that the arithmetic is done with (non-zero) addresses that have the same number of bits as npos.

And, what more, for most iterators + is defined only such that there are enough valid iterator locations after the current iterator; violating that results in UB (which in this case is subtracting 1 from a random access iterator).  But really, the point is you shouldn't add npos to an iterator.

Which gets to the crux of the matter. The OP's mistake was not that npos == -1, or that he misunderstood the implicit type conversions that might occur when an unsigned offset is added to an iterator. His error was adding an offset to timestamp.begin() that resulted in an invalid iterator. UB followed. He even checks whether find resulted in npos, but then uses that result as an offset anyway.

@tbxfreeware, what confused me was string.find() behaves slightly different than std::find() algorithm. std::find() returns end() iterator if no elements match and doing str.begin() + itr in that case will copy the entire string. But string.find() return npos instead of string.end() iterator which causes UB.
